# How to perform "RankIF-like" scenarios in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am very new to the Tableau software; the learning experience has been great far!. However, I have just run into the above-mentioned problem type but can't seem to find a workaround in Tableau. Below is a sample of my data:

[image]

I calculated the "Rank_Cost" in column E of the excel file screenshot by using this formula:-

```
  SUMPRODUCT(--(D2=$D$2:$D$8242),--(A2=$A$2:$A$8242),--(B3>$B$2:$B$8242))+1;
```

which is based on the "Date of Event", "Lane ID", and "Cost Per Good" columns.

I then computed column F, "Quartile" by using this formula:-

```
  MATCH(E2,QUARTILE(IF($A$2:$A$8242=A2,$E$2:$E$8242),{0,1,2,3})).
```

I have over 20000 rows of the above data and would like to perform all sort of analysis and create a dashboard in Tableau. Hence excel is not desirable for this task.

I tried to also connect the excel file to tableau with the "Rank_Cost" and "Quartile" fields pre-calculated as a workaround, but these two values fields get distorted (they become aggregations) which is not what I want. When I manipulated those data fields as "discrete", I cannot plot any visuals with them.

I am quite sure there's a workaround in Tableau, but since I am very new to this program, I am currently finding it a little challenging to do something similar to the excel version. I came across a couple of posts on using LOD are as a workaround, but the examples they used do not work for my problem. Hence I decided to post this problem here for help from the community.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: When you ask question and post sample data the best way is to post the data as it is instead of image, as this will help people use the sample data and provide you solution

Comment: what is the formula for rank_cost and quarantile? if you can recreate these formulas in tableau your problem will be solved

Comment: Try using `ATTR()` instead of making them into dimensions (assuming they're constant with respect to your aggregation)

Comment: Siva, my formula for Rank is: SUMPRODUCT(--(D2=$D$2:$D$8242),--(A2=$A$2:$A$8242),--(B3>$B$2:$B$8242))+1, and that of Quartile is: MATCH(E2,QUARTILE(IF($A$2:$A$8242=A2,$E$2:$E$8242),{0,1,2,3})). The problem I am having is re-creating these in Tableau against the backdrop that Tableau does not have anything like "RankIF". This is not cool for Microsoft developers. For example in Python one can do something like: data['Cost_Rank'] = data.groupby(['Lane_Id','Mini_Bid_Date_2'])['New_Cost_Per_Load'].rank(method='first', ascending=True).

Comment: Andy, do you mean use ATTR() on the pre-calculated 'Rank_Cost' and 'Quartile' fields when I import the data into Tableau?

Comment: I can't decode it doesn't have expertise in excel stuff, can you explain what does this formula do? `SUMPRODUCT(--(D2=$D$2:$D$8242),--(A2=$A$2:$A$8242),--(B3>$B$2:$B$8242))+1,`

Comment: This formula is finding the ranks based and/or grouped by dates (column D)  and lane IDs (Column A). Hope this helps.

Comment: I am still struggling with this issue; is there anyone on here who could kindly assist?